# Get data from every column in every table in a database | SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have seen multiple questions on how to retrieve every column from every table along with its data type, among many other pieces of information which can be summarised in the shortest way with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

However, is it possible to get all the data from the columns and <s>the rows they belong to</s> get the first row in the table alongside this? I have not found a way to do so thus far. Is it possible to do such, maybe also having a `WHERE` condition such as checking if the table contains a list of specific columns before returning it e.g.:

```
SELECT <AllTablesAndColumns+FirstRow> 
FROM <WhereTheyCanBeSelectedFrom> 
WHERE <TheTableHasTheseSpecificColumns>
```

Which would return the table name, column name and the data contained within those columns for each row.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with dynamic SQL, but it will have poor performance.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda That's good to know, I should have specified that I only want to get the first row from every table, shouldn't have as much of an impact performance-wise.

Comment: What do you define as the "first row"? Data in a table is stored as a heap, so a `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` will return a random row. However, if you know how to define e the first row, and it is consistent for **every** table in your database then you could include that in your `ORDER BY`. If the answer is "it depends on the table" getting what you define as the "first row" is going to require someone defining the ordering of **every** tanle, which kind of defeats the point of what you're trying to do, and that you don't want someone doing that.

Comment: This is **very related** (if not to say it's a duplicate) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49674844/5089204). The solution provided there might help you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1)) AS s(n)
<joins>';

DECLARE @joins NVARCHAR(MAX)= '';

SELECT @joins += FORMATMESSAGE('LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM %s ) AS sub%s
       ON 1=1' + CHAR(10), table_schema + '.' + table_name,
       CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) AS VARCHAR(10)))
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT table_schema, table_name
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      -- WHERE ...  -- custom logic based on column type/name/...
     ) s;

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<joins>', @joins);
PRINT @sql;

EXEC(@sql);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9a50b3d7239d5cfd32fab3ca84327230)**

The dynamic query has structure:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES (1)) AS s(n)   -- always 1 row
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.tab1 ) AS sub1 ON 1=1 -- get single row
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.tab2 ) AS sub2 ON 1=1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.tabC ) AS sub3 ON 1=1
```

Please treat it as starting point. You could easily extend it with `WHERE` condition for each subquery and return specific columns instead of *.

---

**EDIT:**

Version with `UNION ALL`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ' UNION ALL', '') + 
FORMATMESSAGE(' SELECT TOP 1 tab_name=''%s'',col_name=''%s'',col_val=%s FROM %s'+CHAR(10) 
      ,table_name, column_name, column_name, table_schema + '.' + table_name)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name LIKE 'colV%'; 

PRINT @sql;  
EXEC(@sql);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2b37c6116763af5893a89369a3c2a77a)**

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks, but how would I combine the select queries into one select instead of joining them onto one row? The reason is that I'm using the SqlDataReader in ADO.NET to read the data coming back. To better illustrate this, all the tables that are selected will have the exact same column names, is it possible to list all the data retrieved from these tables under these column names?

Comment: @AlexanderTolls Yes, you need to rewrite query from `LEFT JOIN` to `UNION ALL` but then you need to make sure that they have compatible datatype. So the output will be like: `SELECT TOP 1 'tab1' AS tab_name, 'col1' AS col_name, col1 AS col_value UNION ALL SELECT TOP 1 'tab2', 'colx', col2 ...`

Comment: thanks again. Right now I'm trying to get more than one column name and column value to be returned, but I'm not able to. I understand right now it returns the table name, column name and the value in that top row, but I am unable to add more column names and values.

Comment: Your second method right now is the best to use. I've realised that since I'm getting the same number of values from each table I can just put a counter in my ADO.NET code to know when a new record is being read. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for more of an EAV structure

Let's say that we're looking for all tables with a column name of **ZIPCODE**

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = ''

SELECT @S = @S +'+(Select top 1 SourceTable='''+A.Table_Name+''',* from '+quotename(A.Table_Name)+' for XML RAW)'
 FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A 
 Where COLUMN_NAME in ('ZipCode')

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Declare @XML xml = '+stuff(@S,1,1,'')+'

Select SourceTable = r.value(''@SourceTable'',''varchar(100)'')
      ,Item        = attr.value(''local-name(.)'',''varchar(100)'')
      ,Value       = attr.value(''.'',''varchar(max)'') 
 From  @XML.nodes(''/row'') as A(r)
 Cross Apply A.r.nodes(''./@*'') AS B(attr)
 Where attr.value(''local-name(.)'',''varchar(100)'') not in (''SourceTable'')
 '
 Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

[image]