# Create table that contains table_name and max_date of each table

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

I have a table with only one column -`Table_Name`, that contains all table names in the database.

How can I create a process that will create another table with all of the names from the table above (`Table_Name`) and a second column with the max update date (`Max_Update_Date`) of each table ?

**Need to pull the value out from the column `Update_Date` from the tables themselves

Here is what I got so far -

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable
select  row_number()over (order by a.Table_Name) as rn, a.Table_Name, s.modify_date 
into #TempMasterTable
from API_Tables a left join sys.tables s
on s.name=a.Table_Name

select * from #TempTable

declare @counter int,
@table nvarchar(50);

set @counter=(select top 1 rn from #TempTable order by rn desc)

while @counter>0
begin
    set @table=( select table_name
    from #TempTable
    where @counter=rn);

    update #TempTable
    set modify_date=(select max([update_date]) from @table)

    set @counter=@counter-1;

end
```

Comment: Please, show the query you have so far and what is wrong with it.

Comment: Have you heard of [`sys.tables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Define exactly what you mean by "max update date". A change to the table's schema? A change to the contents of a table? The last time a row was updated? inserted? deleted? selected?

Comment: The last time the row was update in the table (`update_date` column). @SMor

Comment: There is no easy way to do it, depending on the table numbers you either write it by hand and schedule/trigger it somehow, or maybe write a script which builds the scripts to do this.

Comment: So you want to run a query against a "list of tables" that all contain the column "update_date". You can adapt the dynamic sql in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674844/finding-min-and-max-values-for-all-table-columns) to do that.

Comment: @astentx - I added what I have so far

Comment: @Charlieface - I tried to use it - see above

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly use a table name from parameter in update statement. need to use the dynamic SQL. I have modified based on your requirement

```
DECLARE 
 @id INT
,@tablename VARCHAR(200)
,@TSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempMasterTable
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Table_Name) AS Id
 ,Table_Name AS TableName
 ,ST.modify_date
 INTO #TempMasterTable
 FROM API_Tables  APT 
 LEFT JOIN sys.tables ST
 ON ST.name = APT.Table_Name


DECLARE tablename_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Id,TableName 
FROM #TempMasterTable 


OPEN tablename_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM tablename_cursor INTO @id,@tablename  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    
      SET @TSQL = 'UPDATE #TempMasterTable SET modify_date = (SELECT MAX([update_date]) FROM '+@tablename+') WHERE Id ='+@id      
      EXEC( @TSQL)

      FETCH NEXT FROM tablename_cursor INTO @id,@tablename 

END 

CLOSE tablename_cursor  
DEALLOCATE tablename_cursor
```

Comment: Please look on the example above